# Kronecker Product of Vectors with "all-ones" Vector

Tags: kronecker-product

What is the result of the following Kronecker product?

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} \otimes_K \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} &= \ ?
\end{align*}

Is the "one-vector" any special case or is it simply treated like any other vector and as such, the result is a "stretched version", i.e. two $a$ and two $b$, of the vector on the left side from the product?

I know this is pretty basic but I'm currently working on a problem where it seems not to make sense to have so many duplicates.

Comment: The answer is the "stretched version".

Comment: It's the column ($4 \times 1$) vector with entries $a,b,a,b$

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on the comments and some additional research, the correct answer for my question is as follows:

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} \otimes_K \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} &= \ \begin{bmatrix} a \\ a \\ b \\ b \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}